# skip every nth value in array based on value

Tags: javascript

## The Problem

I'm developing a graph which utilises an `array` of *samples* to build itself. 
Unfortunately, the graph needs to be able to be resized, and therefore some of the samples **must** be removed from the graph.

To *partly* fix the issue, I'm using the modulus (`%`) operator to skip over every *nth* sample in the provided array based on the width of the `canvas` that it is being printed on. So, assuming we **always** have *1800* samples to work with, and the *width* of the `canvas` is `600px`, the `canvas` will skip over every 3rd sample (`1800 / 600 = 3`).

The problem with this is that if the `canvas` has a width of, let's say `720px`, the returned value will be a decimal (`2.5` to be exact) and modulus doesn't exactly like this.

---

## The Code

#### JavaScript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("cvs"),
    samples = [ ... ]; // assume there's 1800 samples here between 0-140

var x = 0,
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// iterate over each of the samples
for(var i = 0; i < samples.length; i++){
    // if there is no remainder when i / (1800 / 720)
    if((i % ((samples.length / canvas.width))) == 0){
        var height = samples[i] * ((canvas.height || 60) / 140);

        // create one bar with appropriate values
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fillRect(
            x + (x * 2), // left
            (canvas.height || 60) - height, // top
            2, // width
            height // height
        );
        ctx.fill();

        x++;
    }   
}
```

#### HTML:

```
<canvas id="cvs" width="720" height="70"></canvas>
```

Essentially, as many samples as possible to fit within the `canvas`, by discarding ever *nth* sample based on the *width* of the `canvas`. It is probably some really easy mathematics, but this is all I could come up with thus far.

All help is appreciated, cheers.

Comment: With 1800 samples and a width of 600, wouldn't you want to skip *every two* values? Skipping every third still gives you 1200

Comment: @CertainPerformance skipping every 3 gives me 600. And yes, that's what I'm doing with modulus. But the problem is the graph isn't **always** a width of `600px`, it can be changed depending on screen size, page, and user preference - most of which output decimals when divided against the width of the `canvas`.

Comment: drawing 1800 samples is not a big deal. Just draw them all. when it is a factor 10 or 100 more you might calculate a statistic on a group of points to reduce the point count.

Comment: @rioV8 it's not that drawing 1800 samples is hard to do, it's that it literally doesn't fit on the canvas. When you only have enough room for 600 samples, but have 1800, you can't see the "other end" of the data.

Comment: If you skip over "every third sample", which means in some group such as `1-2-3` you skip over **one** of them, giving you something like `1-2`, for example, then you will end up with 1200 values, not 600. Do you mean "*keep* every third sample"? Anyway, the more basic question is in the case of a width of 720 how to you want to select the 720 to use? Before you write code or talk about something not working, you need to know what you are trying to do.

Comment: What is the problem with drawing the sample at x coord `i*(canvasWidth/samples.length)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of thinking of skipping entries in your original, think of taking entries *from* your original. For example if you had an array of fifty items and you want to downsample to 20 (that's the same 2.5 rate) you can take every 2.5th element rounded.

```js
function resize(arr, new_size){
    let orig_size = arr.length
    return Array.from({length: new_size}, (_, i) => 
           arr[Math.floor(i * (orig_size + Math.floor(orig_size/new_size))/new_size)])
}

// take 20 from 50
let arr_size = 50
let arr = Array.from({length: arr_size}, (_, i) => i)
console.log(resize(arr, 20))

// take 19 from 29
arr_size = 29
arr = Array.from({length: arr_size}, (_, i) => i)
console.log(resize(arr, 19))

// take 17 from 200
arr_size = 200
arr = Array.from({length: arr_size}, (_, i) => i)
console.log(resize(arr, 17))
```

Notice that it doesn't take every 2nd or every 3rg, but alternates. This should give you reasonable results for any array and resize value. You could also do a `for` loop from 0 to new length instead of `Array.from` in the function with the same results.

**EDIT: Using a `for` loop to push into a new array**

```js
function resize(arr, new_size){
    let orig_size = arr.length
    let smaller_array = []
    for (let i = 0; i<new_size; i++){
        let large_array_index = Math.floor(i * (orig_size + Math.floor(orig_size/new_size))/new_size)
        smaller_array[i] = arr[large_array_index]
    }
    return smaller_array
}

// take 20 from 50
let arr_size = 50
let arr = Array.from({length: arr_size}, (_, i) => i)
console.log(resize(arr, 20))
```

Comment: How would I use a `for` loop as opposed to the `.from()` method? Probably extremely easy, but I've never used it before so I have no idea how it works haha.
But yes, this seems like exactly what I need. +1 :)

Comment: Hey @GROVER. I was simply imaging looping and pushing into an array using the same formula in the array.from to index the big array.

Comment: Any possibility of updating your answer? :)

Comment: Sure @GROVER. see edit. It just loops over from 0 to the length of your smaller array and computes the right index in the large array.

Comment: Ah I get it now! Don't know how I didn't see this before! Perfect workaround, thanks :D

Comment: @MarkMeyer: Why calculate the constant factor `(orig_size + Math.floor(orig_size/new_size))/new_size` each time in the loop?

Comment: That’s a good point @rioV8. It should be moved out of the loop.